# Why typescript cannot refer the type in my example correctly?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, option-type, functor

Considering the code for `Option` ADT as below (pretty similar to [fp-ts Option](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/Option.ts)):

```
export type Option<A> = Some<A> | None

export interface Some<A> {
  _tag: 'Some'
  value: A
}

export interface None {
  _tag: 'None'
}

export const some = <A>(x: A): Option<A> => 
  ({ _tag: 'Some', value: x })

export const none: Option<never> = 
  { _tag: 'None' }

export const isNone = <A>(x: Option<A>): x is None => 
  x._tag === 'None'

type Match = <A, B>(onNone: () => B, onSome: (a: A) => B)
  => (x: Option<A>) => B
  
const match: Match = (onNone, onSome) => x =>
  isNone(x) ? onNone() : onSome(x.value)
```

I'm trying to write the Option map Functor `mapOption`, but it cannot refer the types correctly. You can also see the error in this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7APAQQHxQLxQGUkBbCTHAHygDlUIAoehFYCAJwDMBDAY2iNLkoAb3pQoAfWBcA5gC4oAcgERFYqADcuAGwCuEBRnoBfRs1ade0WimijxU2QsU3VJxj1QBnYFC8lofEwAGiwACgAPQwBKBThEVCFcHHUw4UlpeSUVRWDNHX0FCKhjaI9vXxQ6OPhkdFsNdhx8dXTHLJc6RRLylB8oBC9XPCgQ8KjYWsTsWKhiwZo6PBTxCIA6drxcfE7bNXpQSCgAWS5gHgALEZCoACFw1FcFMOjlu7zUFWeuGLfbsvEySgkRqCXQMz%206nonj6vmIZ0uClO5yu%20DCjzoHxQKleQOKyXUg1ckVeAH4oBjbC8oApPgFImstHoIGUDuBoKcwPE6tcMHl7mEOM8JhhcTh-m9BT9JmDyGKZXU0PdoRUoPCuVMUEiuBqwSMOG9uG94Siwql5VVbMFUkz9PKOGFbSzolLokA).

```
type MapOption = <A, B>(f: (x: A) => B) => (fa: Option<A>) => Option<B>
const mapOption: MapOption = f => fa => match(
  () => none,
  (value) => f(value))(fa)
```

For some reason it is inferring the types incorrectly. How can I fix the typing error?

Comment: ① I think you must mean "infer" instead or "refer".  Could you [edit] to fix that? ② Could you [edit] demonstrate how "inlining the types inside `mapOption`" would fix the typing error and then we look at helping you avoid it?  I tried to do it but I'm having trouble, and when I try to fix it I end up changing your *implementation* to `const mapOption: MapOption = f => match(() => none, value => some(f(value)))`, which type-checks fine but maybe I'm missing the point?  Help!

Comment: Thank you @jcalz, I fixed the question and you are correct! my implementation was incorrect. I needed to wrap my value in some to make it an Option.

The interesting part is, when you make the implementation of a the function point-free, the type error goes away, and that's completely enough. But can you help me understand why literally calling the `match` with `fa`, makes `value` to be inferred to `unknown`?

Comment: I'm confused by the question: you're wondering why an incorrect implementation would result in inference failure? (Generally things fall back to `unknown` if they can't be inferred).  I'm not sure what the alternative could be, but maybe I'm not getting it.  Could you [edit] to present a [mre] something where the only problem present is the inference issue?  Or leave it as-is and I'll write up the answer saying the reason it fails is that the implementation is incorrect.  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: When I was writing the question, I wasn't realize my mistake. My implementation was incorrect, so obviously it was giving me typing error. you caught it, Thank you @jcalz. If you write an answer I will mark it as the solution, so you get the credit and points. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code was that it was not correct, so really there's no hope at all of the compiler inferring the types properly.  The proper implementation looks like this:

```
const mapOption: MapOption = f => fa => (
  match(
    () => none,
    value => some(f(value)) // error!
    // -----------> ~~~~~
    // Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A'.
  )
)(fa);
```

But, as you can see, *the inference issue remains*.  The compiler fails to infer the type of `value` from [context](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing), and thus it falls back to [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).

This sort of thing is ultimately a design limitation of TypeScript.  The language can't always infer [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments and simultaneously infer types from context.  The currently open issue about the general problem is [microsoft/TypeScript#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599).

While there have been improvements here over the years, it's probably always going to be there in some form. TypeScript does not use a *full [unificiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science))* algorithm for type inference, as in some other functional programming languages, and as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134).

And it probably never will use such an algorithm, since (according to [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#17520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17520#issuecomment-318935065)), the current inference algorithm "has the distinct advantage of being able to make partial inferences in incomplete code which is hugely beneficial to statement completion in IDEs."

---

We have to work around this if you want your code to compile.  One way is to do the thing you don't want to do: "inline" the types.  Maybe like this:

```
const mapOption: MapOption = f => fa => (
  match(
    () => none,
    (value: Parameters<typeof f>[0]) => some(f(value))
  )
)(fa);
```

Here I'm using [the `Parameters` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) to get a handle on the anonymous generic type parameter corresponding to `A`.  Otherwise you'd have to do it very explicitly and actually declare the type parameters:

```
const mapOption3: MapOption = <A, B>(f: (x: A) => B) => (fa: Option<A>) => (
  match(
    () => none,
    (value: A) => some(f(value))
  )
)(fa);
```

Another workaround is to make use of some [point-free style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) to eliminate `fa` and thus make type inference easier by shortening the "distance" between the expected return type and the required input type:

```
const mapOption: MapOption = f => match(
  () => none,
  value => some(f(value))
);
```

This way is probably ideal for the particular code example, but you might need to resort to one of the earlier approaches in general.  Without full unification, you'll have to specify types in some places where they might have otherwise been inferred.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=31&ssc=9&pln=30&pc=42#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7APAQQHxQLxQGUkBbCTHAHygDlUIAoehFYCAJwDMBDAY2iNLkoAb3pQoAfWBcA5gC4oAcgERFYqADcuAGwCuEBRnoBfRs1ade0WimijxU2QsU3VJxj1QBnYFC8lofEwAGiwACgAPQwBKBThEVCFcLHUw4UlpeSUVRWDNHX0FCKhjaI9vXxQ6OPhkdFsNdhxcdXTHLJc6RRLylB8oBC9XPCgQ8KjYWsTsWKhiwZo6PBTxCIA6drxcfE7bNXpQSCgAWS5gHgALEZCoACFw1FcFMOjlu7zUFWeuGLfbsvEySgkRqCXQMz+vX6xDOlwUp3OV3wYUedA+KBUryBxWS6kGrkirwA-FBUbYXlAFJ8ApE1lo9BAygdwNBTmB4nVrhg8vcwhxnhMMFicP83nyfpMweRhZK6mh7ox6J4+r4Yeypih4Vx1WCRhw3twxeoYYiwupxBSgVVbMFzfkGW9-KQ+WF6fpoq8APSeqDsNhINgAQjt3qgAFoI5Go2GcAA-ePxkM+jBsGS6UgsUn6w7QRS6FAAayqAHcUN0FlVfFwvF4EDIUFwAEbaaDAJBQMBcNhcUgWLNQHNKDCKNbqMrRcXRADciuV0O1HNQAEYtTrOfh9UCTZczRaZdaILbxG7AjgnRAXSePfRp1DVQuNQAmVeLlB6g1cI3ibcXXfiYH7midqugUBhQAACl2PYQBYXhoDmSD6hwWAANoAAwALoyuel6gde4jjpOM5KhUUBqq+ADML4alyPLhPywKCjKopAuKoJyhCrHGrCv7AYBNrASevxAjhHAgQy+FQIR3C3kAA)